# Writing a function based on two related dictionaries as input

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I want to write a function in Python. Given the `upstream_costs` dictionary, which contains estimated cost (in millions of dollars) of certain oil/gas field operations under four different categories (Drilling, Completion, Facilities, and #Operation), and the `planned_expenses` dictionary which contains a list of wells and corresponding list of planned operations to be executed on each well. My code below seems not to be working and takes forever.

The function should give the following for each well in the `planned_expenses` dictionary: the well name, the unique categories of operations planned for the well, and the total cost of planned operations.

```
"""
The function must take the following arguments:
    
The "upstream_costs" dictionary
Well name
list of planned operations
    
    
upstream_costs = {'Drilling':[['Well Casing',0.2],['Cementing',0.1]],
                     'Completion':[['Tubing',0.2],['Packers',0.1],['Frack Fluids',0.1]],
                     'Facilities':[['Separators',0.2],['Dehydrators',0.1]],
                     'Operation':[['Artificial Lift',0.2],['Workover',0.1],['Transportation',0.2]]}
    
planned_expenses = {'Well-001':['Cementing','Tubing','Packers'],
                       'Well-002':['Tubing','Packers','Separators','Dehydrators'],
                       'Well-003':['Tubing','Frack Fluids','Artificial Lift'],
                      'Well-004':['Separators','Tubing','Frack Fluids','Workover']}
    
    
Expected Output:
    
['Well-001', {'Drilling', 'Completion'}, 0.4]
    
['Well-002', {'Facilities', 'Completion'}, 0.6]
    
['Well-003', {'Operation', 'Completion'}, 0.5] 
       
['Well-004', {'Facilities', 'Operation', 'Completion'}, 0.6]

"""
def expense_by_well(well_name, upstream_costs, planned_operations):
        sum_expenses = []
        jobs = []
        for k,v in planned_expenses.items():
            if k!= well_name:
                print('the selected well name is not included in the planned wells')
            else:
                while well_name == k:
                    for k2,v2 in upstream_costs.items():
                        for i,j in enumerate(v):
                            for x,y in enumerate(j):
                                for i2,j2 in enumerate(v2):
                                    for i3, j3 in enumerate(j2):
                                        if y == j3:
                                            jobs = jobs.append(k2)
                                            if list_of_operations == numpy.in1d(planned_operations, [item for sublist in list(planned_expenses.values()) for item in sublist]):
                                                for i in planned_operations:
                                                    sum_expenses = sum_expenses.append(j3[i3+1])
                                            else:
                                                print('this plan of operation not yet decided')
                                        else:
                                            pass
                                       
    return list(well_name, set(jobs), sum_expenses)
```

Comment: woah, lot of `for` loops

Comment: Looks like a task for pandas, the Python library.

Comment: can you walk us through your thought process while writing your code? it will help to steer you in the right direction

Comment: Nine nested loops at the inner one liner is why it's taking forever. This is so convoluted.

Comment: @barker I wanted to relate the two dictionaries nested values since using those many nested for loops.

Comment: The *first* problem I see: `for k,v in planned_expenses.items()`. remove this `for` loop. just access `planned_expenses[well_name]`, catching KeyError if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem with this approach is the nested loops. This makes the operation completion time grow exponentially.

To solve for that issue, you can do two things. One: pre-clean the data. Two: place a break statement when the value you are searching for is found.

##### Pre-Cleaning Data:

```
upstream_costs_cleaned = {}

for k, val_list in upstream_costs.items():
    transform = [tuple(val) for val in val_list]
    upstream_costs_cleaned[k] = dict(transform)
```

This will output:

```
upstream_costs_cleaned = {
    'Drilling': {'Well Casing': 0.2, 'Cementing': 0.1},
    'Completion': {'Tubing': 0.2, 'Packers': 0.1,
    'Frack Fluids': 0.1},
    'Facilities': {'Separators': 0.2, 'Dehydrators': 0.1},
    'Operation': {'Artificial Lift': 0.2, 'Workover': 0.1, 'Transportation': 0.2}
}
```

Now that the data is cleaned up the loops will be less complicated and you won't need to nest as many of them. Also now we can easily break out of one of the inner loops once we find the value we are looking for.

##### Loop cleaning and adding a Break statement:

```
output = []

for planned_key, planned_val in planned_expenses.items():
    operations = []
    sum_expenses = 0

    for key in planned_val:
        for cost_key, cost_val in upstream_costs_cleaned.items():
            if key in cost_val.keys():
                if cost_key not in operations:
                    operations.append(cost_key)
                sum_expenses += cost_val[key]
                break # Once the value is found, we no longer need to keep looping this iteration.

    output.append([planned_key, operations, sum_expenses])

print(output)
```

This will print out:

```
[
    ['Well-001', ['Drilling', 'Completion'], 0.4],
    ['Well-002', ['Completion', 'Facilities'], 0.6],
    ['Well-003', ['Completion', 'Operation'], 0.5],
    ['Well-004', ['Facilities', 'Completion', 'Operation'], 0.6]
]
```

Note the order of the oil/field operations is not guaranteed because we are using standard dictionaries in python. If the order matters, this same code can be implemented with `OrderedDict`.

##### Completed Code

```
upstream_costs_cleaned = {}

for k, val_list in upstream_costs.items():
    transform = [tuple(val) for val in val_list]
    upstream_costs_cleaned[k] = dict(transform)


output = []

for planned_key, planned_val in planned_expenses.items():
    operations = []
    sum_expenses = 0

    for key in planned_val:
        for cost_key, cost_val in upstream_costs_cleaned.items():
            if key in cost_val.keys():
                if cost_key not in operations:
                    operations.append(cost_key)
                sum_expenses += cost_val[key]
                break

    output.append([planned_key, operations, sum_expenses])

print(output)
```

##### Edit:

Also, for clarity and easy of maintainability, when multiple loops are involved, it's better to name your loop variables a distinguishable name. Especially when you are dealing with nested loops.